# Kentico Cloud Swift SDK not returning items

Tags: swift, kentico, kentico-kontent

I'm testing out the Kentico Cloud Swift SDK to return some 'article' content types (I have created two of them and they are published).

I am using the Boilerplate code as described [here:](https://github.com/Kentico/cloud-sdk-swift)

The result I get is : `[Kentico Cloud] Getting items action has succeeded. Received nil items.`

My code:

```
let client = DeliveryClient.init(projectId: <project id>, previewApiKey: <preview key>, secureApiKey: <secure key>, enableDebugLogging: true)

func getArticles(){

    // Note: Using "items" as custom query returns all content items,
    // but to map them to a single model, a filter is needed.
    let customQuery = "items?system.type=article"

    // More about strongly-typed models https://github.com/Kentico/cloud-sdk-swift#using-strongly-typed-models
    client.getItems(modelType: Article.self, customQuery: customQuery) { (isSuccess, itemsResponse, error) in
        if isSuccess {

    // We get here and itemsResponse != nil but items == nil

            if let articles = itemsResponse?.items {
                for article in articles {


                }
            }
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this error message would appear before `ObjectMapper` is triggered to convert the JSON into Article objects. I could be wrong though.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE
Interestingly, if I request a single article object like so ...

```
client.getItem(modelType: Article.self, itemName: <codename>) { (isSuccess, itemResponse, error) in
            if isSuccess {

                if let article = itemResponse?.item {
                    // Use your item here
                }
            } else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

... then it works. I get the Article object. It's just asking for all of the articles that fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to investigate the issue later today, however, from your description, it might be caused by the Delivery API item readiness delay - the project was not fully synced with the delivery API yet. After the publishing/unpublishing item or creating/generating the project, there might be a small delay in processing messages by Delivery API which could cause unavailability of item. This delay might be variable - from my experience, it may vary from a couple of seconds to 2-3 minutes. Nevertheless, I'm going to check it just to be sure. I'll keep you updated.

Edit: I'm pretty sure the project was not synced and processed on the Delivery API at the time you were requested the items. The API returned *200*, which caused *isSuccess* in the callback to be *true*, however, there might have been none or just a subset of items available - I've reproduced this behavior (screenshot below), although it's by design (the content/messages in Event Hub must be processed asynchronously).

I've also suggested the improvement for Kentico Cloud's documentation to mention/explain the possible delay caused by [processing events queue messages from Event Hubs](https://kenticocloud.com/blog/building-cloud-first-headless-cms).

[image: debug items property]

Just to be sure - could you try it again with your `getArticles` custom query?

Edit2: Back to your question about the `ObjectMapper`. This is not an error just a debug message, however, there shouldn't be probably `nil` but `0` (zero) in the debug message. This message came from:

```
    private func sendGetItemsRequest<T>(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, ItemsResponse<T>?, Error?) -> ()) where T: Mappable {
    sessionManager.request(url, headers: self.headers).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ItemsResponse<T>>) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let deliveryItems = value
                if self.isDebugLoggingEnabled {
                    print("[Kentico Cloud] Getting items action has succeeded. Received \(String(describing: deliveryItems.items?.count)) items.")
                }
                completionHandler(true, deliveryItems, nil)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            if self.isDebugLoggingEnabled {
                print("[Kentico Cloud] Getting items action has failed. Check requested URL: \(url)")
            }
            completionHandler(false, nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My code works consistently now: [Kentico Cloud] Getting items action has succeeded. Received Optional(2) items.

Comment: The delay in processing the project or the items would have been substantial though, I was trying the call for a long time, but it only started working AFTER I requested the single item.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's just a coincidence - I'm not familiar with any internal process that could condition getting all items vs getting just one item.  However, if you experience any suspicious behavior in the future, let me know. End of all - it's software and there might be some glitch.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is very weird. After checking the API by requesting an individual item (see the update in the post above), and getting a result (woot). It now seems the original code (unchanged) now works.

I'm wondering if it takes a while for the data to propagate and be available in the API?

Who knows. Weird.